# How do I use a WPF TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate with LINQ to Entities?

Tags: wpf, linq, entity-framework, data-binding, xaml

I've got a Page class in my .edmx ADO.NET Entity Data Model file with with Parent and Children properties.  It's for a hierarchy of Pages.

*removed dead ImageShack link - ADO.NET Entity Framework Hierarchical Page Class*

This is handled in my SQL database with a ParentId foreign key in the Page table bound to the Id primary key of that same Page table.

How do I display this hierarchy in a WPF TreeView?

Comment: Your image link seems to have broken. If you still have the original image, please reupload it to stack.imgur, or just edit your question to make it work without the image. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got this working with help from [Abe Heidebrecht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9268/abe-heidebrecht).  Much thanks to him.

Here's my XAML...

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageManager"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Name="Window1">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Margin="12" Name="TreeViewPages" ItemsSource="{Binding}" TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewPages_Expanded">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Page}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ShortTitle}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's my Visual Basic code...

```vb
Class Window1

    Private Sub Window1_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        Dim db As New PageEntities
        Dim RootPage = From p In db.Page.Include("Children") _
                       Where (p.Parent Is Nothing) _
                       Select p
        TreeViewPages.ItemsSource = RootPage
    End Sub

    Private Sub TreeViewPages_Expanded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim ExpandedTreeViewItem As TreeViewItem = DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, TreeViewItem)
        Dim PageId As Guid = DirectCast(ExpandedTreeViewItem.DataContext, Page).Id
        Dim db As New PageEntities
        Dim ChildPages = From p In db.Page.Include("Children") _
                         Where p.Parent.Id = PageId _
                         Select p
        ExpandedTreeViewItem.ItemsSource = ChildPages
    End Sub
End Class
```

When the window loads, the root node and its children are queried from the database and inserted into the tree.

Each time a node is expanded, that node's children and grandchildren are queried from the database and inserted into the tree.

Comment: With such codebehind you can use `DataTemplate` instead of `<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Page}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">`

Answer (score 5):

A different way: (well, very similar, but slightly different)

In your Window Load function:

```
PageEntities db = new PageEntities();
TreeViewPages.ItemsSource = db.Page.Where(u=>u.Parent==null);
```

Create a new file Page.cs

```
public partial class Page {
    public ObjectQuery<Page> LoadedChildren {
        get {
            var ret = Children;
            if(ret.IsLoaded==false) ret.Load();
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

In your XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="TreeViewPages">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemSource="{Binding LoadedChildren}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortTitle}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Its not tested, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: This method loads the entire hierarchy all at once.  The previously accepted answer is on-demand loading of child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Second solution worked best for me.  I have a list of recursive objects, so this is the XAML that I used:

```
<TreeView Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="trvVaults" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">
    <!--  Treeview ItemsSource is loaded programmatically  -->
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Vaults}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Each 'Vault' object has several properties (name, location, etc) and a generic list of 'Vaults'.