# How to Bind Treeview with collection of items

Tags: wpf, vb.net, treeview

I have a class :

```
Public Class treeModel

    Public Property title As String
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property items As List(Of treeModel) 'Sons

End Class
```

this class contains metadata about each item and a list of it's sons , How to bind this class to WPF Treeview controller ? , and when item selected How can I access it's metadata ?

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind to the nested collection of objects to your treeView you need to define a `Hierarchical DataTemplate` along with `DataTemplate` in your view. If it's something new to you, these links might be helpful to you -

[WPF TreeView binding](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/wpf/thread/187ce3d2-f7ea-4488-b172-299a684222fb) and [Binding with treeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272854/wpf-treeview-binding) or let a search engine do the honours for you - [Search for Binding to treeView in WPF](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=binding%20to%20treeview%20wpf)